# How accurately did Victory Through Air Power portray the state of the war at the time?

Tags: world-war-two, historical-accuracy, movies

I have just watched Disney's 1943 wartime propaganda film, [Victory Through Air Power](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Through_Air_Power_(film)). The film (which was based on Alexander P. de Seversky's book by the same name) was intended to convince government officials and the public that in order to win the war, the U.S. needed to focus their efforts on producing long-range aircraft, especially bombers.

In order to make it's point, the film spends considerable time describing the war up to that point, focusing on the impact of air forces, as well as the state of supply lines. Since the film is a contemporary source, my assumption is that it is historically accurate. But it *is* a propaganda film with an agenda, so it's possible that it twisted some facts to support its arguments.

**How accurately does the film depict the first few years of the war?**

If that is too broad a question, then I am especially interested in the accuracy of the following two claims made by the film.

1. Early in the war, Germany and Japan chose to spearhead their invasions with their air forces, whereas the Allies were more focused on land and naval forces. The choice to lead with air forces allowed Germany and Japan to overcome the Allies in France, Norway and the Pacific.
2. Germany's attempted invasion of Great Britain failed because Britain's air force was superior to Germany's.

*Prior research: Googling my question turned up little information on the film other than what's on Wikipedia. The Wikipedia articles on the film and on de Seversky focus on the impact of the film rather than it's accuracy.*

Comment: I am **so** itching to write an elaborate answer to this, especially the 2. part, but I just don't have the time. Luftwaffe was larger, better equipped, and better trained than the RAF at the time. But it was asked to fight a battle it was not designed for (long-range strategic attacks instead of short-range tactical support), while RAF did what it *was* designed for, defending Britain. Also, "attempted invasion" is a bit much. Germany tried to create a "credible threat" to force Britain to the negotiating table and out of the war. Germany did not want, nor could afford, to occupy Britain.

Comment: Generally speaking: "Since the film is a contemporary source, my assumption is that it is historically accurate." -- To the contrary, war-time contemporary sources are *less* reliant. This is a *war propaganga film*. You should look at it with the same amount of skepticism as e.g. [Sieg im Westen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieg_im_Westen).

Comment: @DevSolar - Was thinking the same thing. I'm not familiar with the film, but reading about it I kept thinking about how Herman Goering would have loved to have produced such a thing (and may well have). He was constantly making overblown (and in retrospect highly inaccurate) claims about what the Luftwaffe could accomplish on its own.

Comment: Given that the apparent intention of the film was to promote the importance of airpower, I don't see any reason why the film would not have tried to present an accurate impression of the importance of airpower, based on the producer's understanding of the war's progress to date. What would be the purpose of deliberate misrepresentation of this issue by Disney? Goering had a personal vested interest, but did Disney?

Comment: @AgentOrange Seversky wrote an opinion piece, Disney read it and decided to make a movie of it *to advocate the idea* of what was, essentially, a war crime. There was no motivation to correctly represent facts, or give a balanced analysis, whatsoever.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomber_Mafia : Airpower was new, tech was evolving fast, new tech was often overrated, and disagreements on doctrine were probably sincere. Both sides had their exaggerations and mishaps we can see on retrospect. Probably Disney was just the filmmaker guy in the Bomber Mafia camp. There are books on this: https://www.amazon.com/Bomber-Mafia-Temptation-Longest-Second/dp/0316296619

Comment: @DevSolar They did not see it as a war crime. They presumed: a) bombers cripple war production ==> war ends quickly w/ less total loss of life; b) civilian factory workers are legal targets as they produce war material; c) bombers in formation win against fighters. a) b) depend on bombing accuracy. How much / when these assumptions would be proved false, and how the doctrine changed, was and is the interesting discussion. e.g. Is a neighborhood populated mostly by factory workers a legitimate target? When bombers proved to be not so accurate and superior to fighters, this question appeared.

Comment: @Luiz Well, they did see it as a war crime when Germany bltzed Guernica, Rotterdam, and Warsaw. But now the tide had turned, so they changed the tune, and turning whole cities to rubble (Area Bombing Directive, Operation Gomorrha) was *fair play* "because it helped win the war quicker"...

Comment: @DevSolar these weren't factory cities... terror/morale is a different aim than crippling production.. and in 39/40 the Bomber Mafia still believed they could aim factories. The doctrinal change from targeting factories -> workers neighborhoods -> cities -> hiroshima is exactly one of the subjects of discussion where morality was increasingly fuzzy. But in 42/43 it was still going on: "we have 1000s bombers, but we finally understood bombing factories is not as easy as we expected. What do we do with them?" ; "the enemy bombed our cities! don't we have to answer in kind?"

Comment: Never seen the movie . .  but I've read the book; can put my hands on it in the time it takes to walk across the room.  Bomber Mafia at its best

Comment: @DevSolar The relevant decisions had already been made well before 1943 when the film was released. The bombers were already in the air and rolling off the production lines. The film was more likely a propaganda piece to justify the imminent mass bombing campaign to the US public, and preempt the "war crime" critique with a "they did it first" narrative...